# How can i get the path of dlls when using Ninject binding?

Tags: path, ninject, bind

My web app is in 'D:\WebApp folder' and there is a dll in 'D:\Bin' folder , I want to using ninject bindthe dll using the relative path instead of using the absolutely path 'D:\Bin' directly, since the absolutely path maybe changed somewhere.

the code like the following:

```
string path="how to get the path";
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesInPath("path")
.SelectAllClasses()
.BindDefaultInterface());
```

How can i got the path in the code?

Answer (score 1):

The path can be relative from the working dir e.g. "..\bin\the.dll". Make sure the path is in the probing path configuration of the application.